# Mathematica version 10.2 does not find C compiler

Tags: ccompilerdriver

I am running *Mathematica* 10.2 on Windows 7 (64bit) and when I want to use the C compiler I get the message:

> *A C compiler cannot be found on your system. Please consult the
>   documentation to learn how to set up suitable compilers.*

I have done the following:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
```

then `CCompilers[]`gives Out= {}

`CCompilers[Full]` gives

> ```
> {"Name" -> "Intel Compiler", 
>  "Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`IntelCompiler`IntelCompiler, 
>  "CompilerInstallation" -> None, 
>  "CompilerName" -> Automatic}, {"Name" -> "Generic C Compiler", 
>  "Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler, 
>  "CompilerInstallation" -> None, "CompilerName" -> Automatic}}
> ```

though I have Visual Studio 2015 installed. (I have compiled "Hello World" as console application in VS and it worked there, convincing me that I do have a C compiler).
For `GetEnvironment[]`I get

> ```
> {... "VS140COMNTOOLS" -> "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio \14.0\\Common7\\Tools\\", ...}
> ```

(though when I look up this directory I don't see a compiler in there, but the C compiler (cl.exe) seems to be in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin).

How can I tell *Mathematica* where to find the C compiler?

Cheers, Bernhard

Comment: It doesn't support VS 2015 (and neither does 10.3, unfortunately).  But it's easy to fix that, just follow the above link.

Comment: I found an answer that worked here: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/548006 . After manually addind the path to VS 2015 in the system file "VisualStudioCompiler.m" and restarting Mathematica it worked. Cheers!

Comment: In fact that Wolfram Community thread is linking to the same post I mentioned above.